# How can I track my bitcoins to the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, address, balance, blockchain-explorer

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question; I'm just trying to learn more about Bitcoin and the blockchain.   How would I identify the bitcoins that are mine within the blockchain?    I can use Trezor to see my balance, but how would I find those coins within the blockchain without a 3rd party solution like Trezor?   I have used Blockchain Explorer but I used my transaction number or wallet address to find my coin balance. What if you don't have the transaction numbers or wallet address

Answer (score 2):

> **how would I find those coins within the blockchain without a [wallet]**

One way would be to write down a list of addresses that your wallet reports as having a balance.

You can then enter those addresses into any one of the many "blockchain explorer" websites, the website will show you the balance for that address.

> **What if you don't have the transaction numbers or wallet address**

There's generally no way to check the balance outside a wallet unless you have those pieces of information.

The Bitcoin blockchain does not contain any information about people or wallets. The blockchain is simply a list of transactions. For most standard types of transactions you can calculate addresses from the data in a transaction.

Addresses are just a number and are not like postal addresses or network addresses.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use your public address (like an account number) associated with your wallet.
2. Search for your address on a block explorer (like blockchain.com).
3. See your transaction history and balance.
4. Each transaction has a unique ID (TXID) for tracking.
5. Remember, private keys control ownership and transactions.

Understanding this helps you monitor your bitcoin activity and verify your funds on the blockchain. If I misunderstood your question, please point out